# Why some softwares like chrome show weird kind of glitch text in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

some softwares like chrome and ccleaner have weird kind of text display issues in my windows 10, why?[image]

more screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9ieK.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Both apps CCleaner and Chrome use your system font preferences which could cause things to look pretty strange. Check your font settings and see if your default font has changed due to an accident or malware. You can also change the fonts of chrome specifically in the app if you want it to be different than your system.